# SourceTree - remove waiting pushes

Tags: git, push, commit, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree

How do I remove commits, waiting to be pushed to remote?

[image: 2 pushes waiting]

My situation is, that those queued commits (changes) been already pushed (more bellow) and now the server refuses to accept those as they are behind the HEAD.

I tried resetting to another commit, but when I go back to HEAD, pushes reappear again.

- [SourceTree - undo unpushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865335/sourcetree-undo-unpushed-commits)
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/153791/how-should-i-remove-push-commit-from-sourcetree

Clicking Repository > Refresh Remote Status won't help, it actually added the 2nd waiting push :)

PS: I apologize for my terminology, I'm quite new to git.

.

**Update 1**

Problems started when I were commiting feature2 to master branch. I don't have rights to commit there so it got stuck. Then I commited again to my personal branch, which was OK. Then I got one waiting commit, never to be pushed, even if I select the right (personal) branch when I click Push.

[image]

Comment: Its not an error, its just warning that you files not moved to you git repository,Its shows count until the files are moved to Git repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sourcetree - undo unpushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865335/sourcetree-undo-unpushed-commits)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Git commits form a commit graph.  Branches are just named pointers to commits in that graph.

Given that, your question can be restated as

> My local *master* branch is pointing to a different commit than the remote *master* branch.  How do I make my local *master* branch point to the same commit as the remote *master* branch?

There are two ways to accomplish this.  Move the remote branch (`git push`) or
 move the local branch ([`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)).  As you said, you can't push to the remote *master* branch, so options 1 is off the table, that leaves option 2.

Note that the `reset` operates on the currently checkout branch<sup>1</sup> so you'll first want to make sure you are currently on the *master* branch and then move that branch to the same commit as the remote *master* branch.

```
git checkout master               <--- make sure you're on the master branch
git reset --hard origin/master    <--- put your master branch on the same commit as origin/master
```

Now that *master* and *origin/master* are on the same commit, there should be no commits to push.

---

1. `reset` operates on the current HEAD, but for the sake of this explanation it's easier to think of of it as operating on branches.  For more information see this question: [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)
   .

Comment: for others > git said something about my personal branch and master branch being divergent > suggested to use "git pull" which merged those > then I followed steps above > all OK now

Comment: @teejay Which part is dark magic?  I can update the answer until it's just boring 9 to 5 magic.

Comment: That is very kind of you, but I will stick to [git docs](http://git-scm.com/documentation) to "reverse engineer" this, so you could make more magic for those in need! :o)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried by doing: `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?
In this way, you will have the head again on your local repo. Otherwise, I've seen a funny page that might be useful: http://ibrokegit.com/

Most of the times, this things should be solved by using the command line, instead of the GUI (in this case, SourceTree).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, i've tried that before too, not solved the problem.. buut I had very good laught when I looked at that website, so +1 if u ask me :o)

Comment: Given the commit graph OP added to the question, this isn't the right answer.  It only takes you back one commit.

Comment: The graph was added afterwards.

Comment: Now that the graph is there, wouldn't it make sense to update the answer?

Comment: this one worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423775/remove-waiting-push-in-sourcetree?rq=1