# Remove waiting push in SourceTree

Tags: git, push, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I committed files that I don't want to push. I didn't push yet.

How can I remove the commit?

This is how my screen looks:

[image: change list]

These are the options:

[image: options]

I don't want to undo any changes to the source code!

Comment: I don't want to undo any changes to the source code!! - can you please clarify this moment? If you remove the commit you will definitely undo some changes to the source code. Also it seems there are some uncommitted changes in your local copy. Do you want to save these changes?

Comment: I don't want to push cause I included files that are to large. So I wan't to create a new commit without the large files.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To remove the commit without changing any source code, you need to perform a "mixed" reset.

Right click on the last "good" commit (this will probably be `origin/master`). Select "Reset current branch to this commit."

[image: Reset current branch to this commit]

In the resulting dialog, select "Mixed..." from the drop down and click OK.

[image: Mixed]

Your working copy will remain the same (no files will be changed) but the index will be reset, meaning that all commits *after* the selected one will be removed from your history.